# How do I save in Grand Theft Auto 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm a new gamer and don't play much. I started playing yesterday and I get to a point where I finish robbing the bank and then killing the cops to get in the car that crosses the train. After the prologue I take control of Franklin who is with Lamar. I then steal a car and chase Lamar. I never finish that part but then next time it starts all over again.

How do I save it so I can start from where I steal the car and not robbing the bank?

Answer (score 3):

You save the game by either sleeping in a bed in one of the character's safe houses, or selecting the "Quick Save" option on the your mobile phone (neither are available IIRC while in a mission).

To bring up your character's phone, press the Up button on the D-Pad. The Quick Save icon is the one in the left column of the middle row.

Comment: As TZHX says, you can't save whilst in a mission. Unfortunately for you, the first opportunity to save is after the first Franklin mission. If you are really struggling with this mission, I believe if you fail it enough you will get the option to skip it?

Comment: yea, i saw the option to skip and i want to complete it... just want to know how long before i can save it? I got to point where it ask me to loose the cops and then finally asks me to get the car back to dealership....

Comment: Once you return to the car dealership, there should be a cutscene then I think you'll be able to save.

Comment: thats a relief... thanks guys.... by the way, this is an awesome forum... how do i support? donations?

Comment: revenue is ad-based (though I don't think there's any advertising on this particular part of the site at the moment).

Comment: Regarding Arqade, it is very well and strictly moderated. This puts some users off of it and some policies may seem overly harsh, but that contributes to why it is such a useful resource.